# JQuery - How can I select all children that contain a certain attribute but exclude all deeper descendants?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Select all "children" that contain a certain attribute ("attribute_nm") but exclude all children of the children (and so on) that contain the same attribute.

**The "real" case:**

How to adjust this query...

```
$("#main_span").find("[attribute_nm]");
```

... to select only the items appointed below...

```
<span id="main_span">

    <span attribute_nm> <!-- Select that PARENT and its contents! -->

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- DO NOT select that CHILD and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

    </span>

    <span attribute_nm> <!-- Select that PARENT and its contents! -->

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- DO NOT select that CHILD and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

    </span>

    <!-- MORE HTML... -->

</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#main_span").children("[attribute_nm]");
```

https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: TIP: You can use this approach `$("#main_span").find("[attribute_nm]:eq(0)").parent().children("[attribute_nm]");` if the "spans" that you want to select are MORE THAN ONE LEVEL below the "span" containing `id="main_span"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use > to specify direct child.

```js
var elems = $("#main_span").find("> [attribute_nm]")
console.log(elems.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="main_span">

    <span attribute_nm> <!-- Select that PARENT and its contents! -->

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- DO NOT select that CHILD and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

    </span>

    <span attribute_nm> <!-- Select that PARENT and its contents! -->

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- DO NOT select that CHILD and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

        <span attribute_nm> <!-- Do not select that child and its contents! -->
        </span>

        <!-- MORE HTML... -->

    </span>

    <!-- MORE HTML... -->

</span>
```

Comment: We need to stop using the term "direct child". It just confuses matters. There's only one kind of child. Anything else is a descendant of another type.